# tftp-hpa fails to start after upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Perhaps this problem is specific to upgrading an Ubuntu 12.04 that is using tftp-hpa as part of a standard LTSP installation.  After upgrading to 14.04 using do-release-upgrade the tftp-hpa daemon failed to start in a confusing way.

Using either systemV or the upstart method it pretended to start (it would complain if I tried to start it again without first "stopping" it) but no daemon appeared in the ps listing AND any attempt to download something via 
tftp localhost generated a time out.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted as an answer on behalf of the OP)*.

I traced the problem to the `--address` flag by attempting to start the daemon by hand.  It worked if I left out the --address flag altogether but refused to start with any of the standard "0:0:0:0:69" like constructions.

Since "--address TFTP_ADDRESS" is baked into the the upstart script,
it did not work to remove TFTP_ADDRESS entirely from /etc/default/tftp-hpa.  However setting

```
TFTP_ADDRESS :69
```

in `/etc/default/tftp-hpa` seems to have solved the problem.

Also, the upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 left `/var/lib/tftpboot` owned by root, which generated the complaint

> in.tftpd[3084]: cannot set groups for user nobody

in syslog.